# Is there a pentest standard for a web application to nominate it as "secured"?

Tags: web-application

I would like to find a free or paid service which will test my web application and declare whether it's secured or not. Is there such thing which is acceptable by the community or some corporate business units?

Comment: Product recommendations are off topic on this forum.

Comment: @Limit is there away to revise the question, so it will be on topic and useful for other people?

Comment: What is your eventual purpose? Do you want a product or do you want to know if it is possible that you get a guarantee by any of them?

Comment: @Limit I want to know if there is such standard that gives a recognition that my web application is secured

Comment: What is safe today, doesn't mean safe tomorrow. That's just how security works.

Comment: @DigitalFire, there is nothing safe today, yesterday or tomorrow.

Comment: I agree this is off topic as written. In general, there ARE security standards - PCI DSS is a good one to look at - but, in general, security standards, including pentests, tend to be 'point in time' rather than ongoing, which means their value is limited.

Comment: @0x90 if nothing is safe, then you just invalidated your question

Answer (score 3):

> I want to know if there is such standard that gives a recognition that my web application is secured

There is no such "standard". There are various vendors offering services to check your site for vulnerabilities and then allow you to put some seal on the site to show that you've passed there checks. But, the quality of the checks they do is often very limited (depending on what you pay) which means that these seals should not really be trusted. Apart from that anybody can put an image of such a seal on their site even if the site was never checked or just invent their own trust seal to make the site look more trustable.

See also [Sites certified as secure often more vulnerable to hacking, scientists find](https://arstechnica.com/security/2014/12/sites-certified-as-secure-often-morevulnerable-to-hacking-scientists-find/).

If you really want to make sure that your site is mostly secure hire a penetration tester with a good reputation, give him enough time, money and information to analyze your site and follow his advice in securing the site. Better yet, get the help of such testers and security consultants already in the design phase of your web application so that your developers are aware of the problems and build the security into the design of the application instead of trying to add security on top of an inherent insecure application later.